# <Crtl>-<arrow> is not different from <arrow> in virtual console

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal-emulator, virtual-consoles

I rarely use virtual consoles. Thus I just noticed that some of my bash key bindings do not work there. The reason is probably that the key codes (what is shown after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>) for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> are the same i.e. the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> seems not to be recognized with the arrow keys. The regular <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> combinations (<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>...) do work.

- What is the reason for this behaviour?
- How can that be changed?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Indeed. Funny that I cannot close my own question as a duplicate.

Comment: Since you ask, done. :-)

Comment: @Isaac Yeah, my own gold badge didn't work because I added the tag later (or because it's my question).